# Linear Algebra - What are the values of the following determinants?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $$A = \begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{bmatrix}$$ and $|A| = det(A) = 2$. What are the values of the following determinants?

$$a) = \begin{bmatrix}2a&2b&2c\\d&e&f\\g+2d&h+2e&i+2f\end{bmatrix}$$
$$b) = \begin{bmatrix}c&b-c&a\\f&e-f&d\\i&h-i&g\end{bmatrix}$$
$$c) = \begin{bmatrix}c&a&b\\f-3i&d-3g&e-3h\\i&g&h\end{bmatrix}$$

I don't understand the question to be honest, what does it mean to find the values of the following determinants and how would I go about solving for them?

Comment: Adding a multiple of one row to another does $what$ to the determinant? Multiplying a row by a nonzero constant does $what$ to a determinant?

Comment: Do you know what the determinant is? How is the determinant changed if we add one multiple of a row to another row? If we interchange two rows? If we multiple a row by a nonzero constant? You should really know these things before attempting the question and take the time to learn them. The same goes for column operations. Once you know these things the exercise becomes clear.

Answer (score 3):

Three basic properties of determinants:

If you multiply a row by a scalar $k$, then the determinant of the new matrix is $k\cdot\det A$

If you add one row (column) to another, this does not change the determinant. In fact, adding a scalar multiple of one row to another does not change the determinant.

If you interchange two rows (columns), this flips the sign on the determinant.

You should take it from here, as this seems to be HW.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to see how each of these can be obtained from $A$ by performing various row/column operations. For example, you can see that in the first case, the first row is multiplied by 2, and so forth. Then you should think how each of the operations you have determined affect the value of the determinant as they are applied. Knowing the original value of the determinant, you should be able to get the values of the other determinants.